# Show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum(x_i-\bar{x})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

I am supposed to show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})=0$. Next, I will show you my attempt.

> First of all, we notice that the first relation is equivalent to showing that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})=0$. So we will try to prove this last equality.
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)$$
> But I don't know how to show that this last part is equal to zero other than in the trivial case in which $n=1$. Can anyone help me please? Thank, you.

Comment: I must emphasise that $\bar{x}$ refers to the arithmetic mean defined as $\bar{x}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$

Comment: Use parentheses, and different variables for different sums: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j \right)$. – Or simply observe that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \right) - n \bar x$.